# Have there been any indications that Jon Snow's health is failing?

Tags: game-of-thrones

From a story telling perspective I am expecting that John Snow's resurrection will have some kind of significance in future episodes and will be possibly used for dramatic effect. Am expecting him to experience sudden weakness or loss of his "life force" during an important event.

**Have there been already any indications**, since his resurrection, apart from the initial recovery, that Jon Snow suffers from weakness or unstable health or mind, hinting **that his second life is not permanent?**

Comment: Please, tell me how this is opinion based? It's asking for in-show references, not people's opinions on the issue.

Comment: @Catija: Yes, that is exactly what I am asking, but it is less clear with the changed (spoiler free) title.

Comment: I don't think its a terrible question either.  I would point out that Berric Dondarrion has been brought back to life several times by Thoros of Myr.... and although he's not exactly the man he was, there's no suggestion his health is progressively failing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because Jon's resurrection is shrouded somewhat in mystery, we can turn to the next best source for explanation here: Beric Dondarrion.

[image]

If you recall Season 03 of *Game of Thrones*, Beric Dondarrion is the leader of the [Brotherhood Without Banners](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Brotherhood_Without_Banners), accompanied by Thoros of Myr, a red priest of the Lord of Light, just like Melisandre.

Thoros is seen **resurrecting** Beric after he's defeated in combat by Sandor Clegane (a.k.a *The Hound*) by praying to the Lord of Light. We also learn in a later scene that Thoros has provided this service many times ([six times](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Beric_Dondarrion#The_Deaths_of_Dondarrion) at the time).

The side-effects are also, conveniently, discussed in that same scene, where Beric says that **he loses some of his memories and is less himself**, something so awful he would not wish it on Eddard (Arya wishes her father could be brought back this way).

> Thoros:           It's not getting any easier, you know.
>
> Beric:             I know. **Every time I come back, I'm a bit less. Pieces of you get chipped                     away.**
>
> Arya:             (TO THOROS) Could you bring back a man without a head? Not six times, just                     once.
>
> Thoros:          I don't think it works that way child.
>
> Beric:            He's at rest, now, somewhere. I would never wish my life upon him.
>
> <sub>—*Game of Thrones* (S03E05), Kissed by Fire</sub>

It's worth noting that, although Thoros and Melisandre both resurrect their targets in similar fashion (praying to the Lord of Light), and they are both red priests, **Melisandre's ritual is slightly more elaborate** (involves cutting Jon's hair and casting it to the fire, washing his body), and so it's not certain that they are using the same method. Jon's resurrection also had a significant delay, compared to Beric's almost instant.

All things considered, these differences can be plausibly ignored until told otherwise by the show/books, because Melisandre's ritual, compared to Thoros' more improvised, fast and loose method, can be attributed to her own ignorance or adhering to scripture that prescribes more lavishness than required, and Jon Snow's revival delay might be a side-effect of an inexperienced practitioner, a severe delay between death and resurrection, the fact that it's his first resurrection, or simply for dramatic tension purposes (or any combination of these).

Because of all of this, I believe it to be a safe bet to model Jon Snow's resurrection and side-effects after Beric Dondarrion's.

If we make this assumption, then we can say that:

### There are no signs of health failing for Jon.

I make this claim based on the fact that Beric is still alive and healthy in Season 07 of the show, which is roughly 6 years after he was first killed (and resurrected). He maintains this health despite having died (and been resurrected) 5 times more than Jon, all these years later.

For this reason, I think it's a safe bet to make that, at least for the near future, Jon's health is safe, aside from Beric's "I'm a bit less" and some memory loss.

Comment: Something I was tempted to add was that Jon strangling Petyr Baelish in the crypt (Winterfell) could be indicative of some kind of side-effect. It may well be that the resurrection's "Pieces of you get chipped away" includes your ability to manage your anger and emotions - maybe this is why Jon seems to be less capable of dealing with people's bulls\*\*t lately. That's still unclear, as of yet, though, and mostly speculation, so I left it out. Personally, he is less patient because..wouldn't you be? After being backstabbed and brought back from peaceful rest? Still, interesting idea.

Comment: I think "Pieces of you get chipped away" refers to a person's memories like in the books. The person starts forgetting who he was and what he was at a speed which is directly proportional to the number of times he is resurrected.

Comment: `Can I dwell on what I scarce remember? I held a castle on the Marches once, and there was a woman I was pledged to marry, but I could not find that castle today, nor tell you the color of that woman's hair. Who knighted me, old friend? What were my favorite foods? It all fades. Sometimes I think I was born on the bloody grass in that grove of ash, with the taste of fire in my mouth and a hole in my chest. Are you my mother, Thoros?` ASOS-Arya VII

Comment: Being unable to deal with People's BS lately would be a side effect of the Crown imo, not resurrection. Crowns do that to people. Like Bran noted while pleading with his brother that he was now talking to Lord Robb, not his brother Robb. And like Catelyn noted many times how the Crown changed Robb's disposition. Still I suppose as good an answer as we are likely to get +1. The main diff imo however is, Jon has come back only once, while Beric has come back a number of times therefore its logical that Jon doesn't feel like Beric does

Comment: @Aegon I did write the memory loss into my answer (and not just once either). The asker was, if I read it correctly, seemingly after any signs that indicate a sudden, surprise ending to this "second life" for Jon, so I answered in a way that fit that kind of "health failing", while also including that, health failing or not, there are side-effects like being a lesser version of yourself and memory loss. Hope it makes sense. As for my comment regarding anger-management, that was actually just some pure speculation on my part (hence comment not answer) as a reaction to the choking.

Comment: "Melisandre's ritual is slightly more elaborate" Melisandre has been portrayed as someone who _hopes_. She _hoped_ Stannis was Azor Ahai and even fooled herself (she even suffered from confirmation bias). So her elaborate ritual may be an indication of her _effort in trying_ (whereas Thoros has been given the ability without him asking for it). This can be further justified by Melisandre's explicit mentions that she has never resurrected anyone (nor tried to), and is therefore presumably performing the ritual that is written down, rather than channeling a power that she knows she has.

Comment: @Aegon: You're right that Jon has been resurrected once and Beric multiple times. But Lady Stoneheart has also been resurrected once and is _vastly_ different from who she was before.

Comment: @Flater Lady Stoneheart is different from Beric. Beric didn't suffer the pain of a husband's death, death of three sons, death of a daughter. So naturally Stoneheart turned out to be a more vengeful spirit than Beric who was just a young lord, soon to be married, off to do his King's bidding.

Comment: @Aegon: And Jon suffered betrayal by his own brothers, the Night's Watch (on top of the world treating him like a bastard all of his life). I wasn't comparing Stoneheart to Beric, I was comparing Stoneheart to Jon (since they've both been resurrected exactly **once**). If Stoneheart's vengefulness is explained by Cat's resentment of the past, the same can be said of Jon.

Comment: @Flater Pain can't be quantified but I am pretty sure Jon's Pain is no where near Cat's. Jon would be worst than Beric at least, but not as bad as Cat

Comment: @Aegon: That is a moot point. It doesn't matter who was betrayed more. Stoneheart's vengefulness stemming from Cat's resentment **directly sets the precedent** for new-Jon's vengefulness stemming from old-Jon's resentment. It's not about comparing Cat and Jon's pain, it's about proving the point that **resentment can lead to vengefulness**. I'm not arguing about their _degree_ of vengefulness.

Comment: @Flater Cat's resentment is against entire households and regions: Freys and Lannisters.  Jon's would be against the specific group of traitors that killed him.  Which he promptly killed.  Issue resolved. It's also made rather clear that the emotional balance and priorities of these two characters are wildly distinct.  Cat's own feelings and behaviors to Jon set up that she is a vengeful, spiteful woman at her core that won't tolerate people intruding on what she deems "hers" and nothing can change that: not even her desire for Bran to live.